# Could not copy the file pdb because it was not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files

I changed the `Output path` for some projects of my Solution and now I´m getting some errors when I Build my solution. Errors like:

> Could not copy the file "MyProject....pdb" because it was not found...

How could I fix it?

Comment: Do you have an example of the code? probably an typo in the path

Comment: I think you have to copy those files to the new folder location from the original folder.

Comment: Probably there are some post-build actions you have to inspect.

Comment: DaPosto is not an code error. Is a "random" error. When I clean the solution may work fine and may be not. After hours of working fine, I build the solution and I get the same error. This problem appear after change of Output path in the project properties

Comment: @Emesto, could  you visit the previous output path and the new one? Do you find any differences? One possible reason is that the version changes or it is related to the antivirus or others like my following answer, so please check it in your side. If you get any latest information, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Please Uncheck the option "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" from the project property->debug tab and see if that solves your issue.

(2) Please check your previous output and current output path, whether you can get the pdb file in the two folders? I suggest you delete the previous output path like bin/debug or release, and then re-open the project file, clean and rebuild the solution with the new output path, check it again.

(3) I also met this kind of issue which was related to the post-build event, so you need to check it in your side.

(4) Of course, if it is the reference between different projects, please make sure that you add the correct path for this reference and set the "copy local=true" after you change the output path.